# Strange Response from express server

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I created a simple server using expressjs and have post method but I got strange response to post article and I don't know why it happened. Could anyone mind helping me?
my expected is a JSON format.

#### Here is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const articleModel = require('./models/article');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

enter code here

const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/bbs-api');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const bbsRouter = express.Router();

bbsRouter.route('/articles').post( (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // const newArticle = new articleModel(req.body);
    // newArticle.save();
    // res.status(201).send(newArticle);
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.use('/api', bbsRouter);
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!'))
```

#### My postman. I log request body out but it is not as my expectation.

[image]

Comment: data sent in x-www-form-urlencoded can be access thru req.params.field-name

Answer (score 1):

if you are sending form data(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) the you can do

```
bbsRouter.route('/articles').post( (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    // const newArticle = new articleModel(req.body);
    // newArticle.save();
    // res.status(201).send(newArticle);
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I applied `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the wrong request body via postman, your body should be JSON format, not form data

[image]

Comment: I tried it already but still not work. I think the problem come from body-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing body-parser and use middlewares directly from express and set urlencoded to false:

```
   app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
   // support parsing of application/json type post data
   app.use(express.json());
```

See [here](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html) urlencoded option documentation